# 10K Tools "flag" tab issue in revision: 2010.9.5.3

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, 10k

In the 10k tools "flagged" posts tab: Once it is selected, no other tools tabs appear. This requires the user to use the browser back button or click tools again. No other 10k tools tabs exhibit this behavior.

This happens in Firefox 3.6.8 and IE8 on Windows 7 for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug, it's by design.

The flags page is shared between the tools and moderation pages and therefore has no navigation apart from the top bar.

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30336/tabs-missing-for-flags-page-in-the-tools-section)

Comment: Hm, I wonder why I never noticed it until now. Either way, it's off to MSO to downvote Jeff's explanation.